# boost.variant derived type: cannot use copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, variant, boost-variant

I have a type that derives from `boost::variant<T, E>`. I do the following, and I cannot use the copy constructor, I cannot figure out why, some `SFINAE` seems to fail. Looks that the `boost::variant<T, E>` construction is swallowing a `T` as `ExpectedResult<T, E>` in the inherited constructor.
How could I fix it to make it work and with the simplest solution?

```
template <class T, class E>
class ExpectedResult : boost::variant<T, E> {
public:
    using boost::variant<T, E>::variant;
};

ExpectedResult<int,float> er;
ExpectedResult<int, float> er2 = er;


error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::and_<boost::mpl::not_<boost::is_same<Emotiv::Cortex::Utilities::ExpectedResult<int, float>, boost::variant<int, float> > >, boost::detail::variant::is_variant_constructible_from<const Emotiv::Cortex::Utilities::ExpectedResult<int, float> &, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<2>, int, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1>, float, boost::mpl::l_end> > >, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> >, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
        typename boost::enable_if<mpl::and_<
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::variant<int, float>::variant' requested here
    using boost::variant<T, E>::variant;
    while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'ExpectedResult' [with T = Emotiv::Cortex::Utilities::ExpectedResult<int, float>]
    ExpectedResult<int, float> er2 = er;
```

Answer (score 4):

Boost variant has a perfect forwarding constructor.

You are importing it into your class.

It guards against consuming `self&` by checking if `self` is exactly a `boost::variant`.  You are passing it an `ExpectedResult&`.

This confuses it.

```
template <class T, class E>
struct ExpectedResult : boost::variant<T, E> {
  using boost::variant<T, E>::variant;
  ExpectedResult()=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult const&)=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult &&)=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult & o):
    ExpectedResult( const_cast<ExpectedResult const&>(o) )
  {}
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult &&)=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult const&& o):
    ExpectedResult( o ) // calls const& ctor
  {}
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult const&)=default;
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult &&)=default;
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult &) {
    return *this=const_cast<ExpectedResult const&>(o);
  }
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult const&& o){
    return *this = o; // const& assign
  }
};
```

I suspect the above defaulted and manually written special member functions may help.

To be complete, you'd also have to include `volatile`, exploding it by another bunch.

I would be careful about adding my own perfect forwarding constructor as well as a using parent constructor, as the rules for how these change change in C++17 in a possibly breaking way.  I am currently very leery of using inherited constructors due to the breaking changes in C++17 I do not fully understand as yet.

Another approach would be to avoid inheriting construction and instead forward to the variant.

```
template <class T, class E>
struct ExpectedResult : boost::variant<T, E> {
  using base=boost::variant<T, E>;
  ExpectedResult()=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult const&)=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult &&)=default;
  ExpectedResult(ExpectedResult &&)=default;
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult const&)=default;
  ExpectedResult& operator=(ExpectedResult &&)=default;

  template<class T0, class...Ts,
    class=std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_constructible<base, T0, Ts...>::value
      && (
        (sizeof...(ts)!=0)
        || !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T0>, ExpectedResult>::value
      )          
    >
  >
  ExpectedResult(T0&&t0, Ts&&...ts):
    base(std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
  {}
};
```

which is perfect forwarding with all of its imperfections, but close enough for most use.

An `initializer_list<T>, Ts&&...` constructor may make the perfect forwarding more perfect, so `ExpectedResult<std::vector<int>, bool> er{ {1,2,3,4} }` works.

Comment: Should the guard behavior be considered a bug? I find excessive all the necessary replication. Maybe I should submit a bug.

Comment: @GermánDiago The type is probably not designed to be inherited from; but they could change some is_same to is_base_of to possibly make it work in your case.  I don't know if that could cause other problems...